# Application won't crash on purpose while in another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, crash

I'm trying to crash my Console application after a certain amount of time (this is due to me testing whether the application will start itself after crashing. Following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303706.aspx) tutorial)

What I have for this is this piece of code:

```
static class WebSocket
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        Recovery.RegisterForAutostart();
        Recovery.RegisterForRestart();
        Test.Run();

        // some more code
    }
}

public static class Recovery
{
    [Flags]
    public enum RestartRestrictions
    {
        None = 0,
        NotOnCrash = 1,
        NotOnHang = 2,
        NotOnPatch = 4,
        NotOnReboot = 8
    }

    public delegate int RecoveryDelegate(RecoveryData parameter);

    public static class ArrImports
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern void ApplicationRecoveryFinished(
            bool success);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int ApplicationRecoveryInProgress(
            out bool canceled);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetApplicationRecoveryCallback(
            IntPtr processHandle,
            out RecoveryDelegate recoveryCallback,
            out RecoveryData parameter,
            out uint pingInterval,
            out uint flags);

        [DllImport("KERNEL32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int GetApplicationRestartSettings(
            IntPtr process,
            IntPtr commandLine,
            ref uint size,
            out uint flags);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int RegisterApplicationRecoveryCallback(
            RecoveryDelegate recoveryCallback,
            RecoveryData parameter,
            uint pingInterval,
            uint flags);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int RegisterApplicationRestart(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string commandLineArgs,
            int flags);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int UnregisterApplicationRecoveryCallback();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int UnregisterApplicationRestart();
    }

    public class RecoveryData
    {
        string currentUser;

        public RecoveryData(string who)
        {
            currentUser = who;
        }
        public string CurrentUser
        {
            get { return currentUser; }
        }
    }

    //  Restart after crash
    public static void RegisterForRestart()
    {
        // Register for automatic restart if the application was terminated for any reason.
        ArrImports.RegisterApplicationRestart("/restart",
           (int)RestartRestrictions.None);
    }

    //  Start app when PC starts
    public static void RegisterForAutostart()
    {
    #if (!DEBUG)
        RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
        key.SetValue("websocket", @"c:\websocket\run.bat");
    #endif
    }

public static class Test
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        crash();
    }

    static void crash()
    {
        double crashAfter = 1.5 * 60; //  seconds
        int secondsPassed = 0;
        int waitSeconds = 1;

        Console.WriteLine("\nCrash test startet, crash will occour in " + crashAfter + " seconds");

        Timer timer = new Timer(
            delegate (object seconds) {
                secondsPassed += int.Parse(seconds.ToString());
                if (secondsPassed > crashAfter)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Crashing");
                    Environment.FailFast("Test - intentional crash."); // Error happens here
                }
                else
                {
                    double timeUntilCrash = (crashAfter - secondsPassed);
                    Console.WriteLine("Time until crash = " + timeUntilCrash + " seconds");
                }
            },
            waitSeconds,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(waitSeconds),
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(waitSeconds));
    }
}
```

When it's time to crash I get this message:

> Cannot evaluate expression because a thread is stopped at a point
>   where garbage collection is impossible, possibly because the code is
>   optimized.

The checkbox for code optimization is unchecked.

I surpose this is because it's not in the main thread, if this is the case how do I return to the main thread. And if not, what might be the cause?

Comment: That sounds like a debugger message due to you trying to watch some variable while the program is closing down. I suspect your real problem is that the timer is being garbage collected. Try assigning it to a static field rather than holding it in a local stack variable.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: This might be a stupid question, but isn't it already static, hence the `static void crash()` or are you talking about making the `timer` static like `static Timer timer = `?

Comment: As @MatthewWatson pointed out - your Timer object is assigned to a local variable _timer_. When _timer_ goes out of scope on exit from the _crash_ method, there are no references to the Timer object & it is available for garbage collection. The _timer_ variable needs to remain in scope on exit from _crash_, so making it a field of the enclosing class (possibly static) would be a solution.

Comment: @PaulF: Could you show me an eaxmple?

Comment: Outside your `crash()` method define a static timer like so: `static Timer timer;`. Then inside your `crash()` method assign to that by changing `Timer timer = new Timer(` to `timer = new Timer(`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I've already tried that ;-) same result

Comment: What do you mean by "When it's time to crash"? Are you putting a break point somewhere? Are you trying to step through the code? Environment.FailFast is designed to terminate the process with a dump of the process status - the debugger is likely to report that a FatalExecutionEngineError occurred - with error code 0x80131623 somewhere in the message - at this point your application has completely terminated & cannot proceed.

Comment: @PaulF: I want to simulate how the application would behave if an actual crash happened. In the end I want to have my application restart if an error happens, which it is unable to handle. This is why I have the application running for a while before I intentionally tries to crash the application

Comment: I have tried your code - in my small application with your code unmodified, the count down typically stops after around 5 seconds & no error occurs - I am guessing the garbage collector has done its job at that point. Changing to have a static timer as per Matthews suggestion - the countdown goes down to zero & the application "crashes" as expected.

Comment: How are you going to try to restart your application? What sort of crash are you anticipating? FailFast is intended for when the application is in such a state that nothing can be relied on to be working correctly.

Comment: @PaulF: That's interesting, when I run the code in both cases, the timer runs down to zero, and then the error occours when the code reaches `Environment.FailFast`

Comment: @PaulF: I tried to follow this method to restart an application after a crash

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303706.aspx

Comment: Have you got any code optimizations turned on or compiling in release mode?

Comment: @PaulF: As far as I know there's no code optimization added, is there a way to check that? And I've only runned the project in debug mode

Comment: Check in the application properties -> Build -> Optimize code checkbox. Though even with that checked I can still put a breakpoint on either the console.writeline or FailFast lines & program breaks without error. Without more information - maybe more of the application code - I cannot replicate the problem or be of any help.

Comment: @PaulF: The checkbox for `code optimization` is unchecked. I've added some more of the code in hope that it clearifies the problem

Comment: Still works correctly for me - though restart doesn't work in the debugger, but does if run from the command line. Exactly where in your code does the problem occur? What version of Visual Studio are you using.

Comment: @PaulF: I just ran the application as a release outside of VS. And it restartet after the counter hit 0. Now I just have to figure out why it's giving me an error in the console giving be a `System.NullReferenceException` on `Main(Strin[] args)`

Comment: @PaulF: Can you write an aswer so that you can get the credit for it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an application based on your code & found that everything runs as expected when the application is run from the command-line - it is only in Visual Studio debugger the restart does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [PaulF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3070060/paulf) we found the problem. I was testing in `Debug` mode, running the application in release mode outside of Visual Studio fixed the problem. The following `NullReferenceException` was caused by missing command line arguments upon restart.